# HTTP Java Retry Handler with Apache

Tags: java, http

Someone kindly help implement a retry handler for http connections on the code snippet below.

```
public void loadOnStartUp(AppProperties properties) {
    this.mySql = new MySql(properties);
    this.httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler you can see retry mechanism and you can extend it or you can implement it from scratch.

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler()).build();
}
```

You can create custom class implements HttpRequestRetryHandler and implement method of it. By default retry count is 3 you can also change it in DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler.

```
new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(5, false);
```